# Div height doesn't include child elements

Tags: html, css

[image: Reference image]

as seen on the image, the `.widget.main` element's height is only 26 pixels, it doesn't include anything in the `.widget.body` div. if i give it a `margin-bottom` of 300 pixels, this is the result:
[image: With margin-bottom 300]

But that only works for the first 2 widgets, which have the `.scrollable` class, which sets a fixed height. If the div below them doesn't have the scrollable class, it creates issues:
[image: Problem with margin-bottom 300]

How would I go on about making `.widget.main` include `.widget.body`'s height?

Code:

```html
<div class="widget scrollable main" id="archive">
    <div class="widget header">Archive</div>
    <div class="widget body">
        <ul>
            <li>2023</li>
            <ul>
                <li>September</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Yeah</li>
                    <li>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
                </ul>
                <li>August</li>
                <li>July</li>
                <li>June</li>
                <li>May</li>
                <li>April</li>
                <li>March</li>
                <li>February</li>
                <li>January</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="widget scrollable main" id="contributors">
    <div class="widget header">Contributors</div>
    <div class="widget body">
        <p>Placeholder Jack</p>
        <p>Placeholder Jack</p>
        <p>Placeholder Jack</p>
        <p>Placeholder Jack</p>
        <p>Placeholder Jack</p>
        <p>Placeholder Jack</p>
        <p>Placeholder Jack</p>
        <p>Placeholder Jack</p>
        <p>Placeholder Jack</p>
        <p>Placeholder Jack</p>
        <p>Placeholder Jack</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="widget main" id="contact">
    <div class="widget header">Contact</div>
    <div class="widget body">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name-input" placeholder="Name...">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email-input" placeholder="Email...">
        <textarea name="message" id="message-input" cols="25" rows="10" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
        <button>Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="widget main image" id="donate">
    <div class="widget header">Donate</div>
    <div class="widget body">
        <img src="img/donate.png" alt="Donate Button" title="Donate">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.widget.scrollable .widget.body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    max-height: 300px;
}

.widget.image .widget.body img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    padding: 10px;
}

.widget.main.image {
    margin-top: 200px;
}

.widget .widget.body {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    display: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.widget .widget.header {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffb26a;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: black 3px 3px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.widget.main {
    margin-bottom: 300px;
}

.widget#contact .widget.body input {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.widget#contact .widget.body input,
.widget#contact .widget.body textarea {
    width: 100%;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    font-size: small;
}

.widget#contact .widget.body button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    font-size: small;
    background-color: #ffb26a;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

Comment: Without code we can't help you much...

Comment: @SioGabx I edited the post to include the code. My bad

Comment: The .widget.body has position absolute so it doesn’t affect the parent’s height.

Comment: @AHaworth and how can I solve this issue? I want the card's title to look like what I'm showing in the picture

Comment: I removed `position: absolute` and added a `margin-top` of 20px, `margin-left` of 20px, and a `margin-bottom` of -15px. Now even with the `z-index` set to 200, the background is behind the `.widget.body`, but the text is not.

Comment: I have fixed it by adding `position: relative` to it. Thank you for the assistance!